# Review block for spam misclassification - message clarification

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I have had my review rights removed for 7 days due to marking an answer as "Looks OK" when others have marked it as spam. I'm unsure that this classification is correct, but I'm not disputing the ban and will take the time to re-read documentation.

I am presented with the message which I find to be a little confusing - in particular the second clause which I've italicised:

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13585080 was obvious spam *and you've approved many other posts which quite clearly weren't*

Is this informing me that:

1) my track record is usually good, however I have marked this answer as OK when it was spam

2) as well as marking this answer as OK when it was spam, I have also marked answers as spam when they are actually OK

I believe that it's option 1, however the wording of the second clause sounds as though it's informing me of a mistake whereas it appears to be informing me of correct classification.

I ask because based on which of the two options it is, I either need to re-read the reviewing documentation (case 1) seriously consider whether I should consider continuing to review until I feel I fully understand my misclassifications (case 2).

Can this wording me improved? Should it be improved?

Comment: The wording and ban was done manually by a moderator

Comment: Can you post the entire ban message? This looks like there is some context missing.

Comment: If that's what the entire message says, then yes, this is a very confusing and unhelpful message. Looks like the moderator involved accidentally hit "submit" before they were done typing. Perhaps they meant to say "and you've approved many other posts which quite clearly weren't [acceptable quality]"?

Comment: @Magisch that's the entire message. I've updated it to include the question URL.

Comment: I didn't realise that this was a human generated message. Very helpful - thank you :)

Comment: TIL Paul Stanley is a lousy spammer.  Hashtag not all Kiss members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you got wasn't an automated ban, it was a manual review ban issued by a moderator.

We can only speculate here since the issuing moderator hasn't had time to come forward, but it seems like they hit send accidentally without finishing typing.
When moderators come across users that approve spam, sometimes they issue manual review bans, usually after further looking at a reviewer's track record.

As cody gray points out, the moderator probably meant something like:

> "and you've approved many other posts which quite clearly weren't
>   [acceptable quality]"?

Which would be both a logical conclusion to the ban message as well as make sense as a ban message.

Answer (score 6):

I'll put my paws up here - that should have read:

> https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13585080 was obvious spam and you've approved many other posts which quite clearly weren't *appropriate*.

Sorry for the confusion.

So yes, I'm sorry to say it's point (2) in your question. Your reviewing was brought to moderator attention via community flags and upon reviewing your reviews there was spam, link only and general garbage posts that had been approved recently. Coupled with your previous review history it was necessary to get a message across (albeit it missing a word) and to give you a time out so that 1) you can review your reviewing and learn from where you've not got it quite right and 2) reduce the risk of rubbish passing successfully through the queues.

Comment: Great - thank you. Message gratefully received :)